# MySQL restart causes double free or corruption using MySQL C API

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I have a c program that maintains a persistent MySQL connection, version 5.1.46.  If I restart mysql while the program is running I get a double free or corruption error as such:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
Shutting down MySQL........ [ OK ]
Starting MySQL.*** glibc detected *** /home/user/a.out: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000b64dd00 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3739471634]
```

I am expecting the connection to automatically reconnect since I have set the MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT option and have not explicitly closed this connection yet.  In addition, the query I am executing is not a char* that I have accidentally set to NULL or deallocated, it is a constant, double quoted string.

Here are a few lines from the resulting core file in gdb

```
#11 0x000000000044ed71 in mysql_send_query (mysql=0x41966aa0, query=0x41966100 "SELECT count (*) from TableA", length=27) at client.c:2894
#12 0x000000000044edd9 in mysql_real_query (mysql=0x602a, query=0x602d <Address 0x602d out of bounds>, length=6) at client.c:2905
#13 0x000000000042b42f in do_query (conn=0x41966aa0, msg=0x41966100 "SELECT count(*) from TableA") at dosql.cpp:20
```

Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running on the server side, and what version of the C API are you using in your client?

Comment: The system I am working on has MySQL server 5.1.46 and I am using the 5.1.46 MySQL-devel package which I believe includes the C API.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Because of a bug in MySQL.

You can try to update to later package, and see if the problem disappears.

Alternatively, run your client program under Valgrind, and it will report the bug in a way that is usable for fixing it. In particular, it will report

- stack trace where the memory was allocated
- stack trace where it has been freed
- stack trace where double-free is happening (should be same as your GDB stack trace)

Given that info, you could report the bug to MySQL developers, and hope it will eventually be fixed.